# Uninstalled Docker Docker - Possible to restore lost docker images

Tags: docker, restore, docker-container, docker-image, docker-desktop

Recently I had to uninstall docker desktop due to an issue I was facing in launching the docker desktop app post a windows update, but I forgot to take backups of the docker images I was working on at that time. When I re-installed docker desktop, I could see that none of the old images exist now. Is there a way to restore those images as they contain some of my important works. The problem is I have not committed or pushed those images to any docker registry or git as well.